# CSS not applied properly to elements created by JQuery, but magically gets corrected on toggling elements in inspect element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a chat interface where I am dynamically adding messages. Below is a sample code inside a send message function.

```
$chatlogs.append(
        $('<div/>', {'class': 'chat self'}).append(
            $('<p/>', {'class': 'chat-message', 'text': text})));
```

[image: Notice that English is truncated on right]

Notice that English is truncated on right. But trust me the CSS is fine.
**When I do inspect element, and toggle (disable and enable again) max-width or margin checkboxes, magically the alignment gets corrected.**

[image] 
[image]

So technically I am making no changes to CSS. I just disabled and re-enabled the element and magically everything was sorted. This clearly means that the CSS is correctly configured. But when you add elements using JS, it's not able to get CSS correctly.

**How do I solve this??**

Comment: A mere hunch, but try adding the `div` as `<div></div>`. Next, you might try adding a blank text node, i.e. `<div> </div>`.

Comment: Without seeing a working example of the problem, including all relevant HTML/CSS/JS we can't really help you

Comment: @Zunino that makes no difference. Using `$('<div />')` to create an element is fine

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan any way to refresh CSS using JQuery call?

Comment: It is frustrating beyond explanation.

Comment: @Harvey you never need to. CSS is automatically applied to new content. This is why I asked for a working demo of your issue, as it's very odd

Comment: Do you have any javascript (custom or from lib) using screen size for anything? the toggle in the inspector might be triggering some event (e.g.: resize) which then will make the "css work again"